# R, padr adding missing rows based on column content

Tags: r, timestamp, time-series, missing-data, padr

I am using padr for the date padding for a data-frame. It added the rows but how can I have them added smartly?

It’s wanted to sort the data-frame by staff and date_time then to add the missing rows in-between for a staff. (the missing between 2 different staffs is not considered as missing)

Here is the data-frame looked like and the expectation.

[image]

I’ve tried sorted the original data but seems it’s not helping the final outcome. How can I have it done? Thank you.

```
df_sorted <- df[with(df, order(staff, date_time)), ]
```

the code:

```
date_time <- c("02/03/2018 00:00","02/03/2018 01:00","02/03/2018 02:00","02/03/2018 03:00","02/03/2018 05:00","02/03/2018 06:00","02/03/2018 07:00","02/03/2018 08:00","02/03/2018 09:00","02/03/2018 10:00","02/03/2018 11:00","02/03/2018 12:00","02/03/2018 13:00","02/03/2018 14:00","02/03/2018 16:00","02/03/2018 17:00","02/03/2018 18:00","02/03/2018 19:00","02/03/2018 21:00","02/03/2018 22:00","02/03/2018 23:00","03/03/2018 00:00","03/03/2018 01:00","03/03/2018 02:00","03/03/2018 04:00","03/03/2018 05:00","03/03/2018 07:00","03/03/2018 08:00","03/03/2018 09:00","03/03/2018 11:00","03/03/2018 12:00","03/03/2018 14:00","03/03/2018 15:00","03/03/2018 17:00","03/03/2018 18:00","03/03/2018 20:00","03/03/2018 22:00","03/03/2018 23:00","04/03/2018 00:00","04/03/2018 01:00","04/03/2018 02:00","04/03/2018 03:00","04/03/2018 05:00","04/03/2018 06:00","04/03/2018 07:00","04/03/2018 08:00","04/03/2018 10:00","04/03/2018 11:00","04/03/2018 12:00","04/03/2018 14:00","04/03/2018 15:00","04/03/2018 16:00","04/03/2018 17:00","04/03/2018 19:00","04/03/2018 20:00","04/03/2018 22:00","04/03/2018 23:00")
staff <- c("Jack","Jack","Kate","Jack","Jack","Jack","Jack","Jack","Jack","Jack","Jack","Jack","Kate","Jack","Jack","Jack","David","David","Jack","Kate","David","David","David","David","David","David","David","David","David","David","David","David","David","David","David","David","Jack","Kate","David","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Kate","Jack")
reading <- c("7.5","8.3","7","6.9","7.1","8.1","8.4","8.8","6","7.1","8.9","7.3","7.4","6.9","11.3","18.8","4.6","6.7","7.7","7.8","7","6.6","6.8","6.7","6.1","7.1","6.3","7.2","6","5.8","6.6","6.5","6.4","7.2","8.4","6.5","6.5","5.5","6.7","7.5","6.5","7.5","7.2","6.3","7.3","8","7","8.2","6.5","6.8","7.5","7","6.1","5.7","6.7","4.3","6.3")
df <- data.frame(date_time, staff, reading)

write.csv(df, "df.csv", row.names = FALSE)

library(padr)
df$date_time<-as.POSIXct(df$date_time,format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
ddf <- pad(df)

write.csv(ddf, "ddf.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will give you your desired output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(padr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
 mutate(date_time = dmy_hm(date_time)) %>% 
 pad(., interval = "hour", group = 'staff')
# A tibble: 172 x 3
# Groups:   staff [3]
#  date_time           staff reading
#  <dttm>              <fct> <fct>  
#1 2018-03-02 18:00:00 David 4.6    
#2 2018-03-02 19:00:00 David 6.7    
#3 2018-03-02 20:00:00 David <NA>   
#4 2018-03-02 21:00:00 David <NA>   
#5 2018-03-02 22:00:00 David <NA>   
#6 2018-03-02 23:00:00 David 7      
#7 2018-03-03 00:00:00 David 6.6    
#8 2018-03-03 01:00:00 David 6.8    
#9 2018-03-03 02:00:00 David 6.7    
#10 2018-03-03 03:00:00 David <NA>   
# ... with 162 more rows
```

The key is to `group` by staff. I hope it helps.